# Dynamic SQL: Advice/Suggestions (Proper use of the Object_ID function)

Tags: dynamic-sql

I am attempting my first Dynamic SQL Statement as a part of a larger Stored Procedure. I am having trouble getting the following to work. I keep getting an error:
"Invalid Column Name 'FD__CLIENT_ADDRESS'

```
DECLARE @SQL        VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @TABLENAME  VARCHAR(100)

SET @TABLENAME = N'FD__CLIENT_ADDRESS'

SET @SQL = 
'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N''AdmissionKey'' AND Object_ID = Object_ID('+ @TABLENAME + '))
    BEGIN
        print ''success''
    END'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

I am open to suggestions, links, tutorials, or whatever else. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the OBJECT_ID function requires a fully qualified table name... ('DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName')... And you need single quotes...

See below...

```
DECLARE @SQL        VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @TABLENAME  VARCHAR(100);

SET @TABLENAME = N'DataBaseName.SchemaName.FD__CLIENT_ADDRESS';

SET @SQL = 
'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N''AdmissionKey'' AND Object_ID = Object_ID('''+ @TABLENAME + '''))
    BEGIN
        print ''success''
    END';
EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Glad to help. :)